# Convert URL Rewrite redirect rule to htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a static SPA like website that uses handlebar.js templates. It works on IIS with the following URL rewrite rule, but I need to move it to a server that uses .htaccess. I'm not sure how to convert the following URL rewrite rule to an .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html?category={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?\.html  /index.html?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```